What is final uniformity in general?
On any set $X$ a (not necessarily set-indexed) family of functions $(f_i\colon X\to Y_i)_{i\in I}$ to uniform spaces $(Y_i)_{i\in I}$ induces a coarsest uniformity which makes all $f_i$ uniformly continuous, called the initial uniformity on $X$ with respect to $(f_i)_{i\in I}$. The initial uniformity has a simple construction: one of its fundamental system of entourages consists of finite intersections of sets of the form $(f_i\times f_i)^{-1}(E_i)$ where $i\in I$ and $E_i$ is an entourage of $Y_i$. (This is from Bourbaki's General Topology, Chapter II, Section 2.)
The existence of final uniformities follows from the existence of initial uniformities and the following result in category theory: a functor $U\colon\mathcal C\to\operatorname{Set}$ is topological (i.e., every $U$-structured source has an initial lift) if and only if every $U$-structured sink has a final lift. (This is the topological duality theorem in Lowen et al. Categorical Topology.) So, for every set $X$ and every family of functions $(f_i\colon Y_i\to X)_{i\in I}$ from uniform spaces $(Y_i)_{i\in I}$, there exists a finest uniformity on $X$ which makes all $f_i$ uniformly continuous.
However, the proof of the topolgical duality theorem does not tell how to construct final structures explicitly. This makes me wonder: does final uniformity have explicit construction in general? I have found some special cases for which final uniformities have an explicit description. For example, for a topological group $G$, the uniformity on the quotient group $G/\operatorname{Cl}\{e\}$ is precisely the final uniformity with respect to the canonical morphism $G\to G/\operatorname{Cl}\{e\}$. Bourbaki's Exercise 3 of Chapter II, Section 2 gives examples of two uniformities whose supremum (which is a special case of final uniformity) equals their intersection. Are there more special cases like these and are these special cases all we can say?

Every uniformity is generated by a family of pseudometrics and the final uniformity is generated by the family of those pseudometrics $d:X\times X\to [0,\infty)$ such that, for every $i\in I$, the pseudometric $(y,z)\mapsto d(f_i(y),f_i(z))$ is uniform on $Y_i$ (i.e., ${(y,z):d(f_i(y),f_i(z))<\varepsilon}$ is an entourage in $Y_i$ for every $\varepsilon>0$), isn't it?

@JochenWengenroth Thank you so much! This is indeed the final uniformity if my verification was right. I don't know why this was so hard for me to find...
